# Can I see php code on my own server?

Tags: php

Php is a server side scripting language.. So, if i make my PC work as a server in a network, will I be able to see the php code executed on my machine? As html is seen on all client PC's?

Comment: Only if your server is the one executing the code: if you have a PHP enabled server, doesn't mean you'll see the PHP source code running on Facebook

Comment: The code is interpreted server-side and the server itself will send you a "compiled" (html) page that you're able to see from a client

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not only will you be able to *see* the php code on your server, you will even have to put it there first. Your server will not run other servers' PHP code if that is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If the webserver is configured correctly then you can only see the code directly on the server as with every other local file on a server/pc.

Other machines that access your internet pages (in case that the php files are for a webpage, as I have seen some usages of php files for maintenance utilities instead of web pages in the past) only see the results of the php code not the php code itself (thus only what you echo or specifically print out to html in another way). This is because the webserver processes the php file and the clients only receive the results of the php files not the source files themselves.

---

Aside from those two cases I've seen it in the past that if a webserver is NOT correctly configured, it can be that the clients see the php code itself instead of the results (as the webserver does not process the php parts). In these cases yes the clients can see the php source (not sure if this is also true for the current versions of webservers though. At least in the past it was that way).

---

As mentioned there exists also the option to use php files as programs that run locally (for example started via a service that calls php myphpfile.php). In these cases it is as in the first case that the sourcefile itself can normally be accessed as every other local file on the server itself, but as it is not in a webserver directory clients (aside from network shares,...) won't be able to see anything of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see your code by using ssh like putty you have to login to your server using a user account of server. Follow the following tutorial. You will be able to log into your server remotely and you can see and even update the files on server.

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1595/Using+SSH+in+PuTTY+%28Windows%29#gs

Answer (score -1):

You can open the folder containing the source PHP files and open them with an appropriate Editor (Notepad++, Sublime Text...)